# Can query tables from different datasets in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery, can a query joins two tables in different datasets?
say If I want to join these two tables, what should I do?
dataset1:table1 and dataset2:table2

Thank you

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far as part of your question. Did you try writing a query?

Comment: i think the question is quite simple and self-explanatory - but still, I second Elliott's comment - in SO we want to see your some efforts so we can provide specific help. So I ideally in your question you should show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT <fields list>
FROM `project.dataset1.table1` t1
JOIN `project.dataset2.table2` t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
```

see more about JOINs in [`documentation`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#join-types)