# Trouble querying tables in multiple datasets in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, analytics

I am trying to query two bigquery tables from two different datasets to get 2 separate columns. I have both tried union and joins but they are not giving me want I need. Below is the query I tried

```
with abagrowth as (
SELECT
  session abas,
  term abat,
  COUNT(distinct studentid) AS acount,
  ROUND(100 * (COUNT(distinct studentid) - LAG(COUNT(distinct studentid), 1) OVER (ORDER BY session)) / LAG(COUNT(distinct studentid), 1) OVER (ORDER BY session),0) || '%' AS agrowth
FROM
  aba.abaresult
GROUP BY
  1,
  2
ORDER BY
  1,
  2),

bidagrowth as (
SELECT
  session bidas,
  term bidat,
  COUNT(distinct studentid) AS bcount,
  ROUND(100 * (COUNT(distinct studentid) - LAG(COUNT(distinct studentid), 1) OVER (ORDER BY session)) / LAG(COUNT(distinct studentid), 1) OVER (ORDER BY session),0) || '%' AS bgrowth
FROM
  bida.bidaresult
GROUP BY
  1,
  2
ORDER BY
  1,
  2)

select abas, agrowth from abagrowth
union all
select bidas, bgrowth from bidagrowth
```

The dataset is similar to this

```
name  subject  session      totalscore
-------------------------------------------
jack  maths    2013/2014         70
jane  maths    2013/2014         65
jill  maths    2013/2014         80
jack  maths    2014/2015         72
jack  eng      2014/2015         87
jane  science  2014/2015         67
jill  maths    2014/2015         70
jerry eng      2014/2015         70
jaasp science  2014/2015         85
```

The table I am trying to get is meant to be in this format or something similar

```
session    agrowth  bgrowth
2013/2014   null     null
2014/2015   10%       11%
2015/2016   5%        2%
```

The figures above are assumed for example sake.

Questions

1. Is this possible with bigquery?
2. If yes, How can one achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the dataset. Yes, you can query two datasets. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327613/can-query-tables-from-different-datasets-in-bigquery). Basically, you just need to indicate the project (optional), dataset and table you're using.

For the data you want to get. You can achieve it using a JOIN rather than UNION. JOINING the tables by session will allow you to have one row per session. Then you can choose what columns to include in your SELECT.

```sql
WITH abagrowth AS (
SELECT
  session,
  term abat,
  COUNT(distinct studentid) AS acount,
  ROUND(100 * (COUNT(distinct studentid) - LAG(COUNT(distinct studentid), 1) OVER (ORDER BY session)) / LAG(COUNT(distinct studentid), 1) OVER (ORDER BY session),0) || '%' AS agrowth
FROM
  aba.abaresult
GROUP BY
  1,
  2
ORDER BY
  1,
  2),

bidagrowth AS (
SELECT
  session,
  term bidat,
  COUNT(distinct studentid) AS bcount,
  ROUND(100 * (COUNT(distinct studentid) - LAG(COUNT(distinct studentid), 1) OVER (ORDER BY session)) / LAG(COUNT(distinct studentid), 1) OVER (ORDER BY session),0) || '%' AS bgrowth
FROM
  bida.bidaresult
GROUP BY
  1,
  2
ORDER BY
  1,
  2)

SELECT aba.session, aba.agrowth, bida.bgrowth
   FROM abagrowth aba
   JOIN bidagrowth bida
        ON aba.session = bida.session
```

UNION will stack the results from the two queries.